# Sorting in Midnight Commander

Tags: sort, mc

How can I make `mc` sort files just lexicographically?

I have the following files in a directory

```
asn-gpD2360-time.pdf
asn-gp-time.pdf
asn-mggpD2360-time.pdf
asn-mggplcfD2360-time.pdf
asn-mggplcf-time.pdf
asn-mggp-time.pdf
```

and when I set sorting by name, I would expect them sorted like this

```
asn-gp-time.pdf
asn-gpD2360-time.pdf
asn-mggp-time.pdf
asn-mggpD2360-time.pdf
asn-mggplcf-time.pdf
asn-mggplcfD2360-time.pdf
```

This is how e.g. python does it:

```
>>> sorted(['asn-gpD2360-time.pdf', 'asn-gp-time.pdf', 'asn-mggpD2360-time.pdf', 'asn-mggplcfD2360-time.pdf', 'asn-mggplcf-time.pdf', 'asn-mggp-time.pdf'])
['asn-gp-time.pdf', 'asn-gpD2360-time.pdf', 'asn-mggp-time.pdf', 'asn-mggpD2360-time.pdf', 'asn-mggplcf-time.pdf', 'asn-mggplcfD2360-time.pdf']
```

Instead, `mc` sorts them as shown in the first list. Why? How can I make it sort like python does?

---

I've tried running it as `LC_COLLATION=C mc`, sorting by "version" and combination of both and I still get this weird sorting.

Comment: **LC_COLLATE**.

Answer (score 5):

Set in the window of MC "left (or right) - Sortorder - case sensitive".